# Dismissing view controllers all at once

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I need to go back all the way to the view controller that presented the first navigation controller. However I haven't dismissed multiple controllers before at once, and when I've tried doing so, it doesn't work. It just goes to the first navigation controller instead of all the way to the one before it.

Here is my current code:

```
[(UINavigationController *)self.presentingViewController  popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

I have a view controller which modally presents the first navigation controller. The first navigation controller screen is called Main View Controller. It then pushes to Login View Controller. Login View Controller does presentViewController to MenuViewController (UIViewController).

I need to get from MenuViewController all the way back to the view that presented the first navigation controller. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
UIViewController *vc = self;
while (vc.presentingViewController != nil) {
    vc = vc.presentingViewController;
}
[vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Isn't it going to be bad for maintainability, hard-coding your structure in there.

Comment: Because in his question, he present 2 times. But I will edit the answer.

Comment: @sahara108 It worked, thank you! I tried this before you edited and it worked great. I feel kind of bummed I didn't think of something so simple. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use NSNotifications.

You can add an observer in your first/root/initial UINavigationController subclass e.g.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(logout:)
                                                 name:@"LogoutNotification"
                                               object:nil];
```

Then in your "logout:" method you have direct control over the initial UINavigationController rather than those further up the hierarchy.

You can then send an NSNotification from anywhere in the app in order to trigger the method.

e.g.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LogoutNotification" object:self];
```